About a circuit with 2 lights on a switch, usually both go on or off with doing the switch
For kitchen-bar area lighting, there are 2 hang down lights, each powered from its own electrical box, they are spaced 24” apart. Both lights simultaneously respond to one wall switch. To hang a new replacement light fixture, I need only a single power connection to it… wired from one of the 2 existing electrical boxes. Should I draw power from the box closest to the switch and just blank off the wires at the second box with wire nuts? There is nothing else on the circuit controlled by the wall switch.

Please clarify. You have two lights controlled by one switch. You have a "new replacement light fixture". Is this fixture replacing one of the existing lights? Or is it going to be a new third light? Or are you removing the two existing lights and mounting only this new single light?

Some pics would help you here, but yes, you could effectively just use one cable, and nut off both ends of the unused cable.  You would need a blanking plate over the unused electrical box, though.

Definitely pictures before answering. Because it is quite possible that there is a /3 cable and unswitched power ongoing to someplace else. Or that the closest existing fixture is actually not closest in the wiring chain to the switch. Or some other possibilities. All of which might make the logical "nut off both ends of the unused cable" not actually possible because it may turn out to be in use even if the 2nd fixture is removed.
